# Obter um valor específico num array

Tags: c#, .net, array, orientação-a-objetos

Eu estou a tentar obter apenas o nome de um elemento de um *array*. Eu quero obter o nome do primeiro elemento do *array* e também o nome do último elemento. Posto o meu método na classe `Carreira`

```
public override string ToString()
    {


        return "Carrer: " + NrCarreira + "\n1st stop: " + VecParagem.First() + "\nlast stop: " + vecParagem.Last();

    }
```

No evento *click* eu tenho isto:

```
Paragem[] vec1 = new Paragem[3];

        vec1[0] = new Paragem(1, "Nome1", "Porto");
        vec1[1] = new Paragem(2, "Nome2", "Maia");
        vec1[2] = new Paragem(3, "Nome3", "Matosinhos");

        Carreira c1 = new Carreira(4, true, true, vec1);

        label5.Text = c1.ToString();
```

Mas eu obtenho o número de carreira que está correto, mas também todas as informações do primeiro e último elemento do *array*. Eu só quero um valor.

O que preciso de alterar no meu método `ToString()`?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que a propriedade que você quer exibir é `Nome`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Carrer: " + NrCarreira 
        + "\n1st stop: " + VecParagem.First().Nome 
        + "\nlast stop: " + VecParagem.Last().Nome;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que você não está pegando o nome. O método do LINQ que retorna o primeiro e o último devolve o objeto todo, a única coisa que precisa fazer é pegar a propriedade específica que deseja, no caso o nome. Assim:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return "Carrer: " + NrCarreira + "\n1st stop: " + VecParagem.First().Nome + "\nlast stop: " + vecParagem.Last().Nome;
}

using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;

public class C {
    public static void Main() {
        var vec1 = new Paragem[3] {
                new Paragem(1, "Nome1", "Porto"),
                new Paragem(2, "Nome2", "Maia"),
                new Paragem(3, "Nome3", "Matosinhos") };
        WriteLine($"Primeiro {vec1.First().Nome} - Ultimo {vec1.Last().Nome}");
    }
}
public class Paragem {
    public Paragem(int id, string nome, string nome2) {
        Id = id;
        Nome = nome;
        Nome2 = nome2;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Nome2 { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/z6k24x). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hDW7Fm). Também [coloquei no meu repositório do GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/GetProperty.cs).

Considero isso um abuso do `ToString()`. Ele não foi feito para formatar informações, ele [existe para efeito de *debug*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4762406/221800) e no máximo fazer alguma conversão simples, que já pode ser considerado abuso, mas todo mundo faz.